# Angular project does not get compiled anymore in Visual Studio 2019 ASP.NET Core

Tags: angular, visual-studio

My project compiled normally in Visual Studio 2017. Then I did some changes and it does not get compiled anymore:

- I did not change any code inside the project
- I updated Angular cli v7 to v8
- I created a second project with Angular v8
- I installed Visual Studio 2019 and .NET Core SDK 3.1.101x64

If I open my first project in VS2017 now, I get an error that the dependencies can not be found.

If I open my first project in VS2019, it worked.

If I open my second project with Angular 8, the code is compiling normally.

If I start the first project with `-ng serve`, the project is compiling normally.

The first project is working on another machine

- I already tried to downgrade Angular v8 to v7
- I removed `out-tsc` and `dist` folders inside `wwwroot`

Any idea where the problem is, or what I can check?

Comment: Did you try downgrading Core?

Comment: Yes, i removed it. But there was also a second installed .NET Core SDK 3.1 (installed with visual studio 2019). This i still have

Comment: It's not about uninstalling it, you just can't target it from 2017 AFAIK.